# Python - SQL Output in an email

Tags: python, sql-server, email

I've the following piece of code, that sends the output of a SQL command using a python applicatino.

```
command = 'osql -E -S sqlconn -d database -Q "set nocount on;select t, COUNT(*) "Count" from risk group by t  " 
output = subprocess.check_output(command)

message = """From:XYZ <xyz@xyz.com>
To: To ABC <abc@abc.com>
Subject: Report for  run

"""
message = message + str(output)
try:
    smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtpserver',25)
    smtpObj.sendmail(sender,receivers,message)

except SMTPException:
    print ('Error in sending email')
```

However, the issue is the email contains messages like \r\n instead of formatting properly.

What could be the better method of formatting and sending in an email properly.

Example email received:

> b' t                       Count       \r\n -----------------------
>   ----------- \r\n 2013-06-04 00:00:00.000        6605 \r\n\r\n'

Comment: It scares me from a security standpoint that you are getting data from a database by running an osql command. You should use pyodbc or sqlalchemy instead.

Comment: @bwbrowning What is the security issue with using osql? It's just a client tool that uses ODBC and it doesn't require or grant any special permissions. It's true that it's [deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162806.aspx) but that's a separate issue.

Comment: If there is any user input in your query, its a security problem. If there isn't user input its ok, buy I would still use python sql libraries because they are easier to work with and give you greater control over the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Python's email module. See the following links:

- http://docs.python.org/2/library/email
- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/05/14/how-to-send-email-with-python/
- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_sending_email.htm

I think the piece you need the most is MIMEText. Something like this should work:

```
email_msg = MIMEText(body)
email_msg["Subject"] = subject
email_msg["From"] = from_addr
email_msg["To"] = to_addr
```

Where body is the contents of the email. Then you just create an smtplib.SMTP object and call it like this:

```
smtp_handle.sendmail(email_msg["From"], email_msg["To"], 
                     email_msg.as_string())
```